# Ruby's "each" methods not iterating over all items in an array?

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I'm trying out the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
a.each do  
  puts "Removing #{a.last}"  
  a.pop  
end
```

but instead of getting all four numbers popped I only get the first 3. Indeed, doing something like puts a.length returns 1 and puts-ing it shows the element "1" is still there.

How do I need to use the method correctly?
(I'm using Ruby 2.0).

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish is print each element of the array as I pop it out.  I'm trying to teach myself Ruby via eBooks and such.  Looks like I've got quite a road ahead of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is happening because you're iterating over the elements of the list while modifying the list.

Try the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
until a.empty? do
  puts "Removing #{a.last}"
  a.pop
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right on the spot.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**
While you are iterating over `a` you are changing it.

**Explanation of Problem**
That means once you have removed an element the each method gets thrown off because suddenly the number of elements `a` contains is one less. And thus indexing is also thrown off.
If I just execute this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each do
  |thing| 
  puts thing
  a.delete(thing)
end
```

I will get the output [1,3].
That is because the following happens:
Before I remove the 1 from the list that is at index 0, the 2 is at index 1.
After the 1 is removed the 2 is at index 0 instead of 1 so not the 2 is the next element that is iterated over but the 3!

*By the way* you can define a local block variable like I did with `thing` to access each element that you iterate over.

**Solution**
In order to get what you want  you need to create a copy and work on that.

```
 a = [1,2,3,4]
 b = a.clone
 a.each do
   |thing|
   puts thing
   b.delete(thing)
 end
```

Now a remains the same while you iterate over it and you change b instead.
So at the end of this loop `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b =[]`.
After you said `a = b` you will have the desired result.

**Of Course** you can adapt this for popping elements from the back. Just make sure to work on a copy so you do not change the element while you are iteration over it.

Comment: Thank you for a very instructive answer. Helpful and lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Some other answers tell why your code does not work.

An alternative way to do it would be like this (provided that you do not have `nil` or `false` in `a`):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
while e = a.pop
  puts "Removing #{e}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for another approch.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output,which makes clear why it seems to you each not getting run with all the array elements. As you are `pop`(ing)[`Array#pop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop), so the elements from the last is deleted. When each passes `2` to the block,then original array `a` is got empty,so `each` stops the iteration.:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
a.each do |i| 
  puts i
  puts "Removing #{a.last}"  
  p a.pop  
  p "========"
end
```

***Output:***

```
1
Removing 4
4
"========"
2
Removing 3
3
"========"
```

So you can use the below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
(0...a.size).each do |i|
p a.pop
end
```

***Output:***

```
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Thank you for an illuminating answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
a.length.times do  
  puts "Removing #{a.last}"  
  a.pop  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.count.times do a.pop and puts "Removing #{a.last + 1 rescue 1}" end
```

Should do the same in a do loop